# Azure Devops, make 'Work Item' field required during PR creation

Tags: azure-devops

Upon creating a pull request from a source to a target branch, is there a possibility to prevent the creation of a pull request if no work item is entered?

I know in branch policies there is the option to prevent merging unless a work item is entered, however I would like to create a PR **only if** a related work item is assigned **a priori**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a branch policy and enforce linked items:

[image]

this is under the following url: https://dev.azure.com/%org%/%project%/_settings/policies

or using the UI: project settings > policies

ps. this will allow to create pull request without those, but wont allow to complete it, which should suit you fine

Comment: Thanks but I know this as I have mentioned in the question. **I want to prevent creation of the PR unless a work item is linked**.

Comment: quite obviously this is the only way of achieving similar functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think this information would help.

Work items: For only add tickets which are prioritized so reviewers get an idea about the tickets which you are pushed/merged.

And Work items are not required when you can create a PR. If you add a ticket then add otherwise it will be blank and create a PR.